# Visual Studio 2013 Unable to access a WCF Web Service hosted locaclly

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-express

I have a windows 8.1 project and a WCF service project in my solution on visual studio 2013.
My services were running fine on local host with IIS Express and now suddenly i am getting this exception whenever i run the project:

**"Unable to connect to Remote Server"**

**"There was no endpoint listening at `http://localhost:'port_number'/'service_name'.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action."**

On the other hand, i can browse the service and add the service reference in the project just fine.

Comment: "Suddenly" => What did you change? Did you switch from IIS Express to IIS? Change the port number of IIS Express? Change a firewall rule? *Is* the service running when you call it? You may be calling the service before it has a chance to start

Comment: can you please share your web.config file

Comment: Not sure to understand, you told "On the other hand, i can browse the service and add the service reference in the project just fine.". So you're sure your service is up and running fine from web browser / VS webreference, but your program itself doesn't find it ? If yes, the problem obviously comes more from the consuming program than from service itself. Are you sure you're program is well configured to access service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what the cause of that was. The problem was indeed in consuming the service and not in the service itself.

I **restored my windows** to a point when everything was working and it solved the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your webconfig below mentioned tag.

```
 <endpoint address="http://localhost:8087/pricedataservice/DataService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" contract="DataService.IDataService"
      name="WSHttpBinding_IDataService" />
```

check your endpoint address is same.